# Python module imports of copied in third party library

Tags: python, python-module

I'm aware that python module import questions are par for the course, and normally I am fairly capable with how it works, however this situation I'm in has fully confused me.

I have a project with structure similar to this:

```
myproj
|- __init__.py
|- somefile.py
```

This is simple and works fine when run on AWS SageMaker in TorchServe (though that isn't really that relevant).

Now I copied in a library to the root of my project, and this subsequently has sub folders (modules) which reference others within it.

```
myproj
|- __init__.py
|- somefile.py
|- third_party_lib
    |- models
    |   |- A.py
    |- utils
        |- B.py
```

In my main `somefile.py` I have an import like

```
from third_party_lib.models.A import XYZ
```

In file A there is an import e.g.

```
from utils.B import XYZ
```

which is where things are failing, there are many internal imports similar to this that aren't resolvable.

The third party lib doesn't have an **init**.py however I tried adding one and that didn't solve things.
I also tried augmenting the PATH with sys.path.append() on the third_party_lib folder.

In this case, as `third_party_lib` is a git subtree not maintained by myself I would prefer to make no changes within it if at-all possible (otherwise things will get messy in the future when pulling upstream updates), however I would be fine placing a **init**.py inside it if required as that's fairly easy to maintain.

I'm at a bit of a loss now and I'm hoping it's one of those simple confusions with how Python module work.

Thanks for any help and if you need more information let me know.

Comment: Does `from myproj.third_party_lib.models.A import XYZ` work? I'm surprised to see `__init__.py` in the root. The parent dir of `myproj` must be on the `sys.path`.

Comment: The __init__.py in the root was just one of my hail mary's over the last day trying to get this working, I didn't originally have that.

I just tried your suggestion of ```from myproj.third_party_lib.model.A import XYZ``` now and got ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproj'```

I'm starting to wonder if in-fact that this is running on TorchServe and folder names may be getting changed etc could be compounding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm embarrassed to admit but this was a stupid error on my part.
In-case anyone experiences similar issues for me it was the way I went about augmenting the sys path

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, (Path(__file__).parent / 'some_folder').resolve())
```

The problem that was very easy to miss is that the item put into the Path array is actually a Path object! not a string, the solution was to wrap that path call in str() e.g.

```
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.insert(0, str((Path(__file__).parent / 'some_folder').resolve()))
```

Such a simple thing to overlook, especially when I was even printing out the sys.path each time but it's very easy to miss the item in the array is actually wrapped in PosixPath("xxxxxxxxxxx") and not a raw str.